# Meaning of a product in which two vectors are on both sides of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

I am trying to understand this formula:

: [image]

What does the expression with a matrix and two vectors mean in the question?

Comment: Try multiplying out $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}\pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$ and $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}\pmatrix{0 \\ 1}$.  Notice anything?  Now try $\pmatrix{1 & 0}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 1}\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$.  How can you use what you just learned (assuming you learned something) to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated in the question, $\vec{e_i}$ is the vector $(0,...,1,...,0)$ with one on the $i^{th}$ position, so the expression tells you to multiply the transpose of the vector $\vec{e_j}$ (with 1 in the $j^{th}$ position and 0 on the rest) by the matrix, and then multiply the result by the vector $\vec{e_k}$ (with 1 in the $k^{th}$ position and 0 on the rest). Note that each of those vectors has n coordinates. The result will be $a_{jk}$.